# Mocking Repository / Func

Tags: mocking, repository, expression, moq

I have this code

```
public ViewResult Index(String u="", String p="")
{
var q = this.repository.First(x => x.UserName == "x" && x.Password == "y");
```

and I mock this with Moq:

```
repository.Setup(method => method.First(
        x => x.UserName == "x" && x.Password == "y"
         )
    ).Returns(foo);
```

This works good.

Now I change the Controllercode:

```
public ViewResult Index(String u="", String p="")
{
var q = this.repository.First(x => x.UserName == u && x.Password == p);
```

But now, I get null in q, so my mocking don't work.
Whats wrong?

Thanks boqus

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I hope those aren't plain text passwords.

The reason you get `q = null` is that

```
x => x.UserName == "x" && x.Password == "y"
```

is not the same as

```
x => x.UserName == u && x.Password == p
```

If you are not interested in verifying the logic, you can match any input like this (assuming that the delegate type received by `First` is `Func<User, bool>`):

```
repository
   .Setup(r => r.First(It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>()))
   .Returns(foo);
```

Otherwise you could test the predicate matches a test user using a callback:

```
var testUser = new User { userName = "", password = "" };

repository
   .Setup(r => r.First(It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>()))
   .Callback<Func<User, bool>>(predicate => Assert.IsTrue(predicate(testUser)))
   .Returns(foo);
```

You could also store the predicate within the callback, then do the assert later in the test method. This is probably better if you want to test the predicate more thoroughly.

Comment: I get the error:  cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<User>' to 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<User,bool>>'

Comment: `Predicate<User>` was my guess, since you do not specify this information in your question. I updated the answer to use `Func<User, bool>`.

Comment: same error:

cannot convert from 'System.Func<User,bool>' to 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<User,bool>>'

Comment: The problem is this code, that don't work:

Expression<Func<User, bool>> exp = It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>();

Converting a Func to a Expression ist the problem.

Comment: I can compile and run with the code above. Please post the complete definition of the repository interface and the user type. Without that, I am just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code under test:

```
public ViewResult Index(String u="", String p="")
{
var q = userRepository.First(x => x.UserName == u && x.Password == p);

if (q==null )
{
  //view login denied
}
else
{
    //view ok
}
```

First variant of unit test code / no compile error, but returns always null when testing:

```
var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
var user = new User {UserName = "x", Password = "y"};

String u="x";
String p = "y";

userRepository.Setup(method => method.First(
    x => x.UserName == u && x.Password == p
    )
).Returns(user);
```

Second variant of unit test code/compile error:

```
var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
var user = new User {UserName = "x", Password = "y"};


// I have broken the code on 2 lines, so that the problem can be seen.
Expression<Func<User, bool>> exp =  It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>();  //here compile error

userRepository.Setup( r => r.First( exp ) ).Returns(user);  //no compile error
```